# Jquery Get all the array elements

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am programming beginner..

**Code**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
       var course_category = "<?php echo $_REQUEST['cities'] ?>";
       alert(course_category); // alerts as Array
   });
```

when i do print_r in php (`print_r($cities);`) i get

```
  Array ( [0] => BLR [1] => DEL [2] => HYD [3] => MUM
```

now i want to print the array in above jquery

**try**

```
 $.each(course_category, function(key,value){
   alert(value); 

}};
```

printns **A,r,r,a,y**

Comment: What does the rendered JavaScript code look like? Looks like a string to me, not an Array.

Comment: it prints A,r,r,a,y... – user1986299

Comment: `var course_category = "<?php echo json_encode($_REQUEST['cities']) ?>";`

Comment: Yes, but it is `var course_category = "A,r,r,a,y";`, that is no array! You buddy, just made a fancy string.

Comment: it is in php - as he mentioned. learn to read.

Comment: `var course_category = "<?php echo implode(',',$_REQUEST['cities']); ?>".split(',');`

Comment: @GamsterKatalin if it has quote  eg : `BLR"D` . this will not works. it's safe to `json_encode`

Comment: Look at Sirko's answer. @rab, json_encode takes care of any unicode char.

Comment: @GamsterKatalin yes `json_encode` is correct! . there is also another issue using implode .. if array is empty `"".split(",")` return `[""]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way is to use JSON:

```
var list = <?php echo json_encode($_REQUEST['cities']); ?>;
```

Comment: var list = "<?php echo json_encode($_REQUEST['cities']); ?>;"
 if i put ""(doble qoute) its not working.. in my server i got php 5
so there without double qoute is not working

Comment: @user1986299 - Something else must be wrong. You shouldn't need double quotes, because the output is supposed to be readable Javascript syntax (that's what JSON is). Try to figure out why it's not working _without_ double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you currently have two problems:

1. Your PHP array is *not* encoded in any way, that JavaScript understand. Just use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) here.
2. If you receive an object (and arrays are just objects for that matter), you can't just output them using `alert()`, if you really want to see the contents. Again, you may use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to solve this.

```
$(function() {
 var course_category = "<?php echo json_encode( $_REQUEST['cities'] ); ?>";
 alert( JSON.stringify( course_category) );
});
```

If you want to use the array contents later on, refer to plain [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loops or jQuery's [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$output = '';
foreach($_REQUEST['cities'] as $city){
    $output .= "'$city',";
}
$output = rtrim(",", $output);
?>
var course_category = [<?php echo $output; ?>];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each` in jQuery to iterate an array

```
  $.each(course_category , function(index, item) {
});
```

Actually i dont know about php.But you can iterate an array using the above code in jQuery